# Putting elements next to a centered element

Tags: html, css

I have a table with an element that I am attempting to center:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ce3JB/

Is there a way to have the middle element be at the center and the two on the side be on the sides of that center element without displacing it(the three elements are not the same size)? Here's an example diagram:

```
|                             |
|        left ctr right       |
|                             |

               ^   ^
               |   |
               |  This and "left" are always next to ctr
               |
The position of the t remains here no matter what is on the left or right
```

What I want is for element "ctr" to stay fixed to the middle of that column regardless of the length of "right" or "left".

Basically, I want, "ctr" in the center, "left" to go as far right as possible until it hits "ctr", and "right" to go as far left as possible until it hits ctr.

The align="center" attribute that I currently have on the table aligns to the center of all its contents. I want it to center all the contents using the center of "ctr" as the pivot (So t should be in the center of the table in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float` CSS property.

Here, your updated fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/Ce3JB/1/

Comment: @zahirdhada the 'testing' text still moves if you remove either element on either side of it. I believe the OP wants the middle text to stay perfectly centered regardless of which elements exist on either side.

Comment: turbo is correct in interpreting my question. I wasn't able to figure how to do this, and just ended up hard-coding percentages for the variable elements that could end up in the cell. Since this was the first answer, and most responsive, I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Ce3JB/6/

```
#one {
    float: left;
}
#two {
    margin: 0 10px;
}
#three {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: @Fags yeah, I think he's trying to get the center element to not move if you remove either side element.